# How to change order in legends and change the size of legends in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

So basically, my data is like this:

```
1stCol 2ndCol 3rdCol

Week1  1     4

Week2  2     3

Week3  3     4

Week4  5     6

...

Week11 7     8

Week12 9     10

...


Till Week 52.
```

I used ggplot to plot this data:

```
ggplot(data, aes(b, c, colour = a)) + geom_line()
```

But the legends will be:

Week1 Week11 Week12... Week19 Then Week2 Week21...

But I want them be

Week1 Week2 Week3 Week4...

Is that possible?

And also, cause I have such a long list for legend, it's so hard to fit them in a jpg( I used ggsave to save it) how can I adjust to that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the legend in order convert ur column into an ordered factor like this.

```
data$1stCol <- factor(data$1stCol,levels=as.character(data$1stCol),ordered = TRUE)
```

This will preserve the order of your column. If you want to add such a large legend you can try adding legend at the bottom by adding this argument in the last.

```
ggplot(data, aes(b, c, colour = a)) + geom_line() + theme(legend.position="bottom")
```

Also you can customize the legend components including size by using various commands like

```
legend.background
legend.margin
legend.key
legend.key.size
legend.key.height
legend.key.width
legend.text
legend.text.align
legend.title
legend.title.align
legend.position
legend.direction
```

Look in ggplot2 manual pdf for examples.http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ggplot2/ggplot2.pdf

Comment: Thanks so much!!That's exactly what I want. However, for the legend, even if I put it in the bottom, it was still too large. I wander is there a way to split a legend into several columns?

Comment: I am not aware whether you can split your legend or not. However a small friendly suggestion, plotting with such a large legend is usually not encouraged given nobody can read and comprehend it. Try to avoid doing that. If my answer worked for you, give a tick mark and accept the answer.